# How to know the process id of the process which executes a given script?

Tags: linux, shell

I have a multiple process running at a time and only one of these process will execute a given shell script.

I do not have access to the source code of these processes, but I have access to the script which is getting called by one of the processes.

Is it possible to modify the script so that I know which process executes the script?

Comment: does it work? ps aux | grep script.sh

Comment: Should I add it inside script.sh ?

Comment: no just run it in your terminl...if it works tell me to add it in answer part :)

Comment: `echo $PPID` from script should do

Comment: Do you want to know the parent process (that starts the script) or do you want to know the child process (the shell that parses and executes the script)?

Comment: I removed the [tag:c] and [tag:csh] tags.  If they were actually correct, please edit the question to indicate how it relates to these topics.

Comment: @tripleee I am working on csh.

Comment: Is the script your program is running an `csh` script also?  Otherwise, your interactive shell has little influence on this topic.

Comment: Please feel free to post an answer yourself and mark it as accepted so that this question no longer shows up as unresolved.  Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Adding  `echo $PPID` in the script works as suggested by @anubhav

Answer (score 0):

You can echo the variable `'$$'` which contains the PID.

then you can use `lsof -p PID` to find who is running your script and what else is opened.

Also you can use `lsof <path/to/your/script.sh>` to see which process is accessing your  script.